# sending multiple array in multiple array in Angular js

Tags: angularjs, arrays, json, angularjs-scope

How to send this data in AngularJS. (It's a multiple array in a multiple array which need to send on one Object)

```
[{
"working_day":"sunday",
"from_time":{"hour":"9","min":"30"},
"to_time":{"hour":"6","min":"30"}
},{
"working_day":"monday",
"from_time":{"hour":"9","min":"30"},
"to_time":{"hour":"6","min":"30"}... and so on for other week days
}]
```

I am trying to send data like this in an API and I am new to AngularJs, so please tell me how can I make this data through HTML at runtime?

```
            $scope.schedule = []; // Hard coded value
            $scope.week = {};
            $scope.week.working_day = "Sunday";
            $scope.week.from_time = {};
            $scope.week.from_time.min = "10:00";
            $scope.week.from_time.max = "5:00";
            $scope.week.to_time = {};
            $scope.week.to_time.min = "2:10";
            $scope.week.to_time.max = "8:00";

    var dataParam =  {
                        "prefix":$scope.data1.prefix,
                        "first_name":$scope.data1.first_name,
                        "password":$scope.data1.password,
                        "last_name":$scope.data1.last_name,
                        "email_id":$scope.data1.email_id,
                        "mobile_number":$scope.data1.mobile_number,
                        "roleCode":[$scope.data1.roleCode],
                        "role":[$scope.data1.role],
                        "Schedule":angular.toJson($scope.schedule.push($scope.week))

                      }
 console.log(angular.toJson(dataParam));
            /* $http({
            url:  "/here",
            method: "POST",
            headers :{'Content-Type': 'application/json','Accept': 'application/json' },
            data: dataParam
            }) .success(function(response) {
                if(response.status_code=="success")
                {
                    $scope.successmsg = response.status_message;

            console.log(angular.toJson(response));
            $state.go('dashboard.setting.user', {'user': $scope.viewUser});
                }
                else {

              $scope.successmsg = response.status_code;
                }

            });  */
```

};

for now i just need to send this data format with angular js, please suggest

this is what i am doing in angular by "hard code" i need to send this data in angular js, how can i do that?

now please help me with html code of angular to send that hard coded value into runtime value by user

Comment: you want to send data from angularjs or want to display this data using angularjs?

Comment: send and fetch accordingly

Comment: Do you want to display this data in HTML also ?

Comment: yes... i do want to fetch also and display it html

Comment: You should use `$http` service [DOC](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Comment: i know how to use http but it is not the issue if you can read the question

Comment: Can you show us your jsfiddle?

Comment: So you are tying to create a form that generates the data above? What have you tried and what specific issues have you run into? If you are looking for documentation on how to create forms in AngularJS there is plenty of good documentation and tutorials.

Comment: @Martin just see the update what i have tried

Comment: Please include the code that calls $http. What error are you getting?

Comment: @Martin thanks for your concern.. but first i need to send the data if i'll make it i'll also fetch it accordingly and will show on html

Comment: I want to see the $http code you are using to send the data. When you say `it won't work` how does it not work? Are you getting a specific error? Please include more information.

Comment: did that... now please help me with html code of angular to send that hard coded value into runtime value by user

Answer (score 0):

Have an array

```
$scope.schedule = [];
```

Create an object with your Json keys

```
$scope.week = {};
$scope.week.working_day = "";
$scope.week.from_time = {};
$scope.week.from_time.min = "";
$scope.week.from_time.max = "";
$scope.week.to_time = {};
$scope.week.to_time.min = "";
$scope.week.to_time.max = "";
```

Push it into array

```
$scope.schedule.push($scope.week);
```

Comment: it is only returning 1

Comment: again returning 1

Comment: send the entire array, returning 1 means..!  show me how you call the API from Js.

Comment: this is simply what i printing on console nd getting array length not the value

`$scope.schedule = [];
    $scope.week = {};
    $scope.week.working_day = "Sunday";
    $scope.week.from_time = {};
    $scope.week.from_time.min = "10:00";
    $scope.week.from_time.max = "5:00";
    $scope.week.to_time = {};
    $scope.week.to_time.min = "2:10";
    $scope.week.to_time.max = "8:00";
    
    
   var dataParam =  {
        "Schedule":$scope.schedule.push($scope.week) // here schedule.push is an array }
        console.log(angular.toJson(dataParam)); `

Comment: change this 
 "Schedule":angular.toJson($scope.schedule.push($scope.week))
to
 "Schedule":angular.toJson($scope.schedule)